# Getting "Property 'FOO' does not exist on type" in TypeScript when adding a property after the object is declared

Tags: typescript

Getting this error in TypeScript:

```
error TS2339: Property 'FOO' does not exist on type '{ stuff ... 201 more ...; }'.

Constants.FOO.forEach((item) => {
          ~~~
```

From this situation:

```
// Constants.js

const Constants = {
  ABC: 123,
  WWW: 'COM',
  // ...
}

// down the line in the same file:

Constants.FOO = [
  Constants.ABC,
  Constants.WWW,
]
```

Then in the file importing this:

```
import Constants from 'Constants'

// Getting the squiggly marks here showing the above error message...
Constants.FOO.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item)
  // 123
  // 'COM'
})
```

How do I resolve this situation? Can I do it without having to rewrite the implementation of `Constants`? Because in my case there are hundreds of instances of this error for different props on `Constants` that are added after the object is constructed.

Note that `Constants.js` is a JS file and not a TS file, ideally we don't have to convert Constants.js to TS as it would be a lot of work in our case. Hopefully there is another workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to manage this would be to declare a second object, copying over the contents of `Constants` in addition to the new `FOO` property:

```
const InitialConstants = {
    ABC: 123,
    WWW: 'COM',
    // ...
};

// down the line in the same file:
const Constants = {
    ...InitialConstants,
    FOO: [
        InitialConstants.ABC,
        InitialConstants.WWW,
    ],
};
```

This way, the combined `Constants` object will be automatically detected by TS to have all required properties, including `FOO`.

Another option is to define the values beforehand:

```
const ABC = 123;
const WWW = 'COM';
const Constants = {
    ABC,
    WWW,
    FOO: [ABC, WWW],
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Is there no other way? I was hoping to not have to rewrite too much stuff...

Comment: Because it could get recursive, where one thing depends on the next depends on the next, etc. so I would have to create all kinds of `InitialConstantsA...B..CDE...` objects.

Comment: Such an object is inherently unfriendly to TS, unfortunately, since its properties can't all be determined at the time the object is initialized. You could also make `FOO` a getter instead, to initialize it all at once, but that'd be kind of weird *and* would still require some refactoring. If I were you, I'd just bite the bullet and refactor it using one of the methods in my answer